# Pasting columns together and then delete the information in one of the columns ? col1= Paste (col1, " ", col2) then clear col2

Tags: r, merge, cell

I need a way to check if the variable `MA Street3` has information in it, if it does, I need to paste the information into `MA Street2`. Both `MA Street2` and `MA Street3` should appear in `MA Street2` and `MA Street3` should be blank.
Here is what I have tried so far:

```
Sp23_Enroll <- Sp23_Enroll %>%
for(i in `MA Street3`) {
  if(is.na(.$`MA Street3`[i])==F){   
    `MA Street2`[i]= paste(`MA Street2`[i]," ", `MA Street3`[i]) %>% 
    `MA Street3`[i] <- "NA" 
}else {(is.na(.$`MA Street3`[i])==T)
 `MA Street3`[i] <- "NA"
}
}
```

I also tried an `ifelse` statement and couldn’t get that to function properly either. A sample [data set](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cZkY9028Ip_9In6bHocNRwWS33ycyE_0/edit?usp=drive_link&ouid=107524988429176375151&rtpof=true&sd=true) can be found here. I feel, I am overthinking this and there is a simple answer I am not seeing.

Comment: It would be best if you copy and paste the output of `dput(Sp23_Enroll)` into your question. So we have the data as you have it in your environment.

Comment: It can also prevent folks from accidentally editing your data which might impact the answers you receive.

Comment: There is a link to the data set. in the post. There is a lot of sensitive data in the dataset that I cannot post online. The posted data set is cut down to only what is needed.

Comment: I meant `dput` of the data you have linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
library(dplyr)

Sp23_Enroll <- Sp23_Enroll %>%
  mutate(
    `MA Street2` = ifelse(!is.na(`MA Street3`), paste(`MA Street2`, `MA Street3`), `MA Street2`), # a space will be between them by default
    `MA Street3` = NA, # set every value of `MA Street3` to NA OR 
#    `MA Street3` = NULL # remove the column `MA Street3` entirely
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

If in fact the values in your columns are `NA` then you could accomplish this a number of ways, but here is a base R solution:

```
Sp23_Enroll <- within(Sp23_Enroll, MA.Street2 <- ifelse(is.na(MA.Street3), MA.Street2, paste(MA.Street2, MA.Street3)))
Sp23_Enroll$MA.Street3 <- NA
```

Or

```
Sp23_Enroll$MA.Street3 <- with(Sp23_Enroll, replace(MA.Street3, is.na(MA.Street3), ""))
Sp23_Enroll$MA.Street2 <- with(Sp23_Enroll, paste(MA.Street2, MA.Street3))
Sp23_Enroll$MA.Street3 <- NA
```

For a tidyverse solution, see the post from @Melissa Key

---

There are a number of things to point out about your attempt:

1. Many functions in R are vectorized. You do not need to loop through your observations to accomplish what you are trying to do (though you certainly can loop, you would be better off leveraging vectorization).
2. Piping your data frame into a for loop will error.
3. Inspect the values of your columns closely. They may not be `NA`, which is a special value in R. Instead they could be empty strings `""`. There are a number of ways to detect empty strings, such as `df$MA.Street3 != ""` or `nchar(df$MA.Street3) > 0`. Whether they are `NA` or `""` can depend on how you read your data into R.
4. You want to replace values with `"NA"` after you have pasted them together. Again, that is just a string to R, where as `NA` (not quoted) has special meaning. There is a lot of R functionality to working with `NA` instead of `"NA"`.
5. The default delimiter of `paste` is a space. By trying to do something like `` paste(`MA Street2`[i]," ", `MA Street3`[i]) `` you are introducing two spaces: one from the default delimiter and the second you specified. This is likely not what you want.
6. `is.na(...)==F` is fine, but R has a negation operator `!` that negates logical values. For example `!is.na(...)` would read, "is *not* NA".

---

If your values are not in fact `NA` but rather `""`:

```
df$MA.Street2 <- paste(df$MA.Street2, df$MA.Street3)
df$MA.Street3[df$MA.Street3 != ""] <- "NA" # Consider NA instead of "NA"
```

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your data, it's difficult to be sure what you need. But it seems that `coalesce`might be helpful:

Toy data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  street1 = c(NA, 1, 2, NA, 4),
  street2 = c(0, NA, NA, 3, NA)
)
```

Solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  mutate(street = coalesce(street1, street2)) %>%
  select(-matches("\\d"))  # this is just *one* way of getting rid of obsolete columns
  street
1      0
2      1
3      2
4      3
5      4
```

One more thing: if indeed you just want to coalesce columns, the the term "paste" as used in the title to your question is misleading and should be replaced by "coalesce" or "merge"